# How can I update my Java version on my Mac so I can install Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm trying to install eclipse on my Mac so I can work on a homework assignment for school. It's a new laptop so I needed to reinstall java on it which I did. Oracle's website said it was going to be the latest version of Java. However when I try and install eclipse I'm getting an error saying:

"Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 7.0 or higher is required."

When I go into terminal and check the version sure enough I get

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

When I go to the Java Control Panel to try and update it there it tells me that I'm up to date saying I have `Java 8 Update 101` but I'm still unable to install eclipse. I have no idea what is wrong and could use some help.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to be doing development work on a Mac, Homebrew is a pretty useful utility

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you download both:

Java Development Kit (JDK)  8 - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 8 - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html and scroll down to mac install instructions for more help

Comment: You're very welcome! just remember that the JDK is for writing java applications in a certain version of java and the JRE let's you run certain java applications! Happy coding @JustinSmith!